# highlightedColor in selected TableViewRow gets stuck

Tags: titanium, tableview, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

See [my screencast](https://vimeo.com/63740196) for an example of what I mean. You see the problem about 20 seconds into the video.

It seems to mostly happen when scrolling the tableview causes the selected row to go off screen. When you scroll to bring that row back onto the screen and then select a new row the previously selected row's highlightedColor stays instead of switching back to the regular color. It doesn't happen *every* time, but this is the the best way I've found to replicate. Here's my Allow code:

**recipe_list.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <TableView id="categories" class="master">
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Appetizers" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Drinks that are extremely complex" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Entrees" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Desserts" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Appetizers" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Drinks that are extremely complex" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Entrees" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Desserts" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Appetizers" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Drinks that are extremely complex" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Entrees" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Desserts" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Appetizers" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Drinks that are extremely complex" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Entrees" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
            <TableViewRow class="category_row">
                <Label class="category" text="Desserts" />
                <View class="separator" />                  
            </TableViewRow>
        </TableView>

        <View id="vertical_separator" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

**recipe_list.tss**

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    top: 0
}

".master": {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 320,
    // height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: "#ebeced",
    separatorColor: "#d7d7d7",
    allowsSelection: true
}

".category_row": {
    selectionStyle: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.BLUE,
    selectedBackgroundColor: "#34c2d8"
}

".category": {
    font: {fontFamily: "Open Sans [Regular]", fontSize: "20"},
    textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    color: "#464646",
    highlightedColor: "#fafdff",
    top: 15,
    bottom: 15,
    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE
}

".separator": {
    top: 0,
    height: 1,
    width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: "#f6f6f7"
}


"#vertical_separator": {
    left: 320,
    width: 1,
    height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor: "#cbcdcf"
}
```

Comment: Try with specifying className for TableView.

Comment: That won't work as you can't change class names programmatically. They have to be hard-coded.